# Открытие формы при верных введенных данных PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, qstackedwidget

Есть три окна : авторизация, регистрация и главная. 
При заполнении полей регистрации (логин, пароль, подтверждение пароля) происходит переход на форму авторизации.

Не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы при введении неверных данных окно авторизации осталось, а при введении верных данных окно авторизации перешло на главную страницу.

---

```
...

class LoginWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, avt.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushlog.clicked.connect(self.loga)

    def loga(self):
        login = self.ulogin.text()
        password = self.upassword.text()

        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                host='localhost',
                port='port',
                database='user',
                user='user',
                password='password'
            )

            cursor = connection.cursor()

            query = "SELECT * FROM autandreg WHERE login=%s AND password=%s"
            values = (login, password)

            cursor.execute(query, values)

            result = cursor.fetchone()

            if result is None:
                print('Неверный логин или пароль')
                return
            
            print('Авторизация прошла успешно')


        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print(f'Ошибка: {error}')

        finally:
            if connection.is_connected():
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()

...
```

Comment: а также вопрос, можно ли реализовать без tkinter ?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: проблемы как таковой нет, тут скорее просто незнание. я предоставил выше код класса авторизации, в который надо внести переход на главную форму при условии, что введены верные данные из базы данных. не могу предоставить минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получать быстрые и правильные ответы, 
**вам надо научиться составлять минимально-воспроизводимый пример**.

Один из возможных вариантов решения вашего вопроса,
кдасс [**QStackedWidget**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstackedwidget.html) предоставляет стек виджетов,
в котором одновременно виден только один виджет.

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class LoginWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.parent = parent 
        
        self.ulogin = QLineEdit('shtuqueen')
        self.upassword = QLineEdit('12345')
        
        self.pushLog = QPushButton('Авторизация')
        self.pushLog.clicked.connect(self.loga)
        
        formlayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.centralwidget)
        formlayout.addRow('Введите логин', self.ulogin) 
        formlayout.addRow('Введите password', self.upassword)
        formlayout.addRow('', self.pushLog)
        
    def loga(self):
        login = self.ulogin.text()
        password = self.upassword.text()

        ''' 
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                host='localhost',
                port='port',
                database='user',
                user='user',
                password='password'
            )

            cursor = connection.cursor()

            query = "SELECT * FROM autandreg WHERE login=%s AND password=%s"
            values = (login, password)

            cursor.execute(query, values)

            result = cursor.fetchone()

            if result is None:
                print('Неверный логин или пароль')
                return
            print('Авторизация прошла успешно')
        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print(f'Ошибка: {error}')
        finally:
            if connection.is_connected():
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()        
        '''

        if login == 'shtuqueen' and password == '12345':
            print('Авторизация прошла успешно')
            # переход на главную форму при условии, 
            # что введены верные данные из базы данных.
            self.parent.stackWidget.setCurrentIndex(3)                    # <----
            self.parent.setWindowTitle('Главная') 
        else:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 
                'Вы ввели Неверный логин или пароль')
        

class RegistrationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RegistrationWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.parent = parent 
        
        self.login = QLineEdit('shtuqueen')
        self.password1 = QLineEdit('12345')
        self.password2 = QLineEdit('12345')
        
        self.pushReg = QPushButton('Зарегистрироваться')
        self.pushReg.clicked.connect(self.rega)
        
        formlayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.centralwidget)
        formlayout.addRow('Введите логин', self.login) 
        formlayout.addRow('Введите password', self.password1)
        formlayout.addRow('Введите password', self.password2)
        formlayout.addRow('', self.pushReg)
        
    def rega(self):
        self.parent.stackWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        

class StartWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):            # ??? , avt.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StartWindow, self).__init__(parent)
#        self.setupUi(self)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.pushsign = QPushButton('Регистрация')
        self.pushlog = QPushButton('Авторизация')
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushsign) 
        layout.addWidget(self.pushlog)         

        
class BasicWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):                                 # <----
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BasicWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QMainWindow {
                border-image: url(boy.jpg) 0 0 0 0  ;                  
            }
        """)
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('На Стартовую страницу')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self._page_0)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)

    def _page_0(self): 
        self.parent.stackWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.parent.setWindowTitle('Стартовая')
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.setWindowTitle('Стартовая')
        
        self.stackWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.stackWidget)
        
        self.page_1 = StartWindow(self)
        self.page_1.pushsign.clicked.connect(self._page_2)
        self.page_1.pushlog.clicked.connect(self._page_3)
        self.stackWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)

        self.page_2 = RegistrationWindow(self)
        self.stackWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        
        self.page_3 = LoginWindow(self)
        self.stackWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)
        
        self.page_4 = BasicWindow(self)                                   # <----
        self.stackWidget.addWidget(self.page_4)
        
    def _page_2(self): 
        self.stackWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.setWindowTitle('Регистрация')
        
    def _page_3(self): 
        self.stackWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.setWindowTitle('Авторизация')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(600, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**boy.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @shtuqueen что не так?